# Math equation and numeric label - align environment

Tags: math-mode, equations, horizontal-alignment, align, labels

I'm writing a large equation for which I need to introduce line breaks in order to make it more legible. I'm using the following code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
        H &= \lambda_{R_x}V_x + \lambda_{R_y}V_y + \lambda_{R_z}V_z \nonumber \\
          &\mathrel{\phantom{=}} \kern+\nulldelimiterspace +\,\lambda_{V_x}\left(\frac{T}{m}\cos{\psi}\cos{\phi}\right) \nonumber \\ 
          &\mathrel{\phantom{=}} \kern+\nulldelimiterspace +\,\lambda_{V_y}\left(\frac{T}{m}\cos{\psi}\sin{\phi}\right) \nonumber \\
          &\mathrel{\phantom{=}} \kern+\nulldelimiterspace +\,\lambda_{V_z}\left(\frac{T}{m}\sin{\psi} - g\right) \nonumber \\
          &\mathrel{\phantom{=}} \kern+\nulldelimiterspace +\,\lambda_{m}\left(-\frac{T}{c}\right) \nonumber \\
          &\mathrel{\phantom{=}} \kern+\nulldelimiterspace +\,\mu_{u}\left(u^2_x + u^2_y + u^2_z -1\right) \nonumber\\
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

The output is the following:

[image]

I don't know what I should modify within the code in order to make the equation number aligned with the last math expression. As you can see, the equation number appears further down.

Comment: Just get rid of the last `\nonumber \\\`

Comment: a @Willoughby said but also why the complicated `\mathrel{\phantom{=}} \kern+\nulldelimiterspace +\,` I would just have written `\quad{}+`

Comment: I tried it @Willoughby, but what I get it's a double label: the first one correctly aligned to the last math expression (as I would), the second one just immediately below the first one.

Comment: The last line of align doesn't need a \\, by adding that you add a new line in the align environment which gets numbered

Comment: Thank you very much both: Willoughby for suggesting me the solution -I'll pay extra attention the next time- and @DavidCarlisle for the great tip, it's a simpler form by far!

Comment: Just for information: where did you get the idea of `\kern\nulldelimiterspace`? “Cabbage for a snack” we'd say in Italy. `;-)`

Comment: I reworked a code that I found in an old post, here in the forum. It was a highly voted answer, but I didn't notice that was a 9 years old post, so probably that's the reason why it had this kind of (super?)-outdated style... "you never stop learning" , as we also say! `:-D` @egreg

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to number only the last equation it is easier to use `aligned` with the `[b]` specifier, which spares you typing all the `\nonumber`s. Note also that your construction to align the `+` signs and get the correct spacing is overly complicated. You can put `&` after `=` and preserve the correct spacing by adding an empty group `={}&`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[b]
H ={}& \lambda_{R_x}V_x + \lambda_{R_y}V_y + \lambda_{R_z} V_z  \\
     &+\lambda_{V_x}\left(\frac{T}{m} \cos\psi \cos\phi\right) \\ 
     &+\lambda_{V_y}\left(\frac{T}{m} \cos\psi \sin\phi\right) \\
     &+\lambda_{V_z}\left(\frac{T}{m} \sin\psi - g\right) \\
     &+\lambda_{m}\left(-\frac{T}{c}\right) \\
     &+\mu_{u} \left(u^2_x + u^2_y + u^2_z -1\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Personally I'd get rid of all `\left`/`\right`, and replace them by `\biggl`/`\biggr`. (Except the last one of course.) (But do you really need them?) Note also that

```
\cos{\psi}
```

isn't doing what you probably think, since `\cos` & Co. take no argument. If you don't want to write `\cos(\psi)`, then `\cos\psi` is absolutely fine.

Comment: That's really useful @campa. Thank you for the complete answer. I was overcomplicating the code!

Answer (score 6):

Here's another `aligned`-based solution, which gets by without having to produce large parentheses.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[b]
H &= \lambda_{R_x}V_x + \lambda_{R_y}V_y + \lambda_{R_z}V_z \\
  &\quad+\frac{T}{m}\bigl(\lambda_{V_x}\cos\psi\cos\phi
                         +\lambda_{V_y}\cos\psi\sin\phi  
                         +\lambda_{V_z}(\sin\psi - g) \bigr) \\
  &\quad-\frac{T}{c}\,\lambda_{m}  +\mu_{u}(u^2_x + u^2_y + u^2_z -1)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```